# Как можно избавиться от верхнего баннера про ХэшКод?

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, хэшкод

Прекрасно понимая необходимость данного баннера *(к слову, с пропущенной запятой)* для **незарегистрированных** пользователей, хотел бы обратить внимание, что для **зарегистрированных** пользователей он как бы не совсем актуален, если не сказать совсем не актуален.
Честно говоря, сложно представить ситуацию, что потенциально новый пользователь зашел на сайт, зарегистрировался и только потом увидел баннер.

Это не принципиально, но хотелось бы, по возможности, избавиться от баннера после регистрации. По крайней мере - на основном сайте.

Comment: Оно уйдёт само по себе через пару недель. Пока же можно убрать своим  стилем  `#system-message {display:none;}` или скриптом     `$("#system-message").hide()`

Comment: Это не баннер как таковой, а featured [вопрос на Мете](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24/). Поэтому наличие/отсутствие регистрации не влияет на его видимость.

Comment: @Nofate отсюда и моя робкая просьба исправить это.

Comment: @Nofate Реквестируем [tag:status-completed].

Comment: @Discord,no-reproduce по-хорошему

Answer (score 3):

Банера уже нет, можно радоваться и закрывать вопрос.

Не забудьте удалить юзер-стили и отключить прочие скрывалки элементов, если вы ими воспользовались. Сверху могут выводиться не только бесполезные надписи, они иногда бывают полезными.

Comment: Да, радуюсь уже несколько дней. Однако не представляю что можно указать в причинах закрытия. Хотел было добавить тэг [meta-tag:status-completed], однако это разрешено только модерам.

Answer (score 1):

Раньше можно было подключать user scripts/styles, но в любимой мной опере (после перехода) такой фичи нет (а нужна бы).
Лично я решил проблему костыльком:
У меня есть расширения для рабочих браузеров, в них я держу самые нужные мне инструменты, этакий швейцарский нож для браузера.
Не долго думая, я добавил файлик стилей, которые подключаются на этом сайте, содержимое: `#system-message{display: none !important;}`.
Иногда просматриваю содержимое - вдруг поменялось.

Так что присоединяюсь к вопросу - ссылка достала, пора бы уже убрать, я думал скоро уберут, а она висит до сих пор.